# Symfony 4 - How to embed children in forms

Tags: php, forms, symfony, tree, symfony4

Let's suppose I have this Document, a [Model Tree Structures with Child References](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/model-tree-structures-with-child-references/)

```
/**
 * @ODM\EmbeddedDocument
 */
class Link
{
    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ODM\Field(type="string")
     */
    private $title;

    //...

    /**
     * @var Link[]
     *
     * @ODM\EmbedMany(targetDocument=Link::class)
     */
    private $children = [];
}
```

I want to create a form for it

```
class LinkType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('title', TextType::class)
            ->add('link', TextType::class)
            ->add('target', TextType::class)
            ->add('children', CollectionType::class, [
                'entry_type' => LinkType::class,
                'allow_add' => true,
                'allow_delete' => true,
            ])
        ;
    }
}
```

I get a 500 error with empty message (nothing in the log). I guess since I'm embedding the same form, it creates a kind of infinite loop...

Have you ever faced this problem before? If so, have you found a solution?

**EDIT 1: More details**

It's an API, using the FOSRest Bundle. The problem is with the update. Here is an example of payload:

```
{
    "title": "Header menu",
    "links": [
        {
            "title": "Home",
            "link": "/",
            "children": []
        },
        {
            "title": "About",
            "link": "/about"
            "children": [
                {
                    "title": "Presentation of WOOHP",
                    "link": "/woohp",
                    "children": []
                },
                {
                    "title": "The team",
                    "link": "/team"
                    "children": [
                        {
                            "title": "The managers",
                            "link": "/managers",
                            "children": []
                        },
                        {
                            "title": "The spies",
                            "link": "/spies",
                            "children": []
                        },
                        {
                            "title": "The scientists",
                            "link": "/scientists",
                            "children": []
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "title": "Our values",
                    "link": "/valus",
                    "children": []
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "title": "Missions",
            "link": "/missions",
            "children": []
        },
        {
            "title": "Contact",
            "link": "https://www.example.com/contact",
            "children": []
        }
    ] 

 }
```

**EDIT 2: More errors**

Thanks to @jakumi, now I have the errors displaying. It's a memory limit error.

```
Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 20480 bytes) in /var/www/api/vendor/symfony/event-dispatcher/EventDispatcher.php on line 197

Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 32768 bytes) in /var/www/api/vendor/symfony/debug/Exception/OutOfMemoryException.php on line 1
```

Comment: well ... are there infinite link loops? if yes, that that's probably a hint, that the children entry_type should not be LinkType, right? just make a "ReducedLinkType" without the children. or add an option which controls adding the children form field. If there are no infinite link loops, then ... say so ;o)

Comment: A "ReduceTypeLink" will just resolve for the first level and I will get error for deeper levels.

I thought it was an infinite loop because the same form is embedded in its children, and each child will embed the same form that is embedded in other children, and so on....

Comment: what do you mean with "error for deeper levels"?

Comment: What I want to achieve is a children tree model. 
`Parent 1 => Child 1 => Child 1.1 => Child 1.1.1 => Child 1.1.1.1`
I added more details in my post

Comment: have you tried payloads without nested children? also a 500 rarely happens without any errors in logs (symfony error log, php error log, server error log). can you check that the problem doesn't exist, if you remove the children form field? can you check if a payload without children works? if there's no logs at all, you have to somehow try some edge cases to find out what the actual problem may be.

Comment: Yes, I always have the error 500 even with a payload without children. And if I remove the field children from the form, it works (without the children in the payload, of course). For the log, I really don't have anything in the symfony log. in the php log, there is just `"PUT /index.php" 500` without details

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/206238/discussion-between-jakumi-and-mario-radomanana).